# Create and update todayworker status without duplicate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
this is my document in worker collection i want when I delete the id. today worker change to 2.
```

Again I will add same id today worker change to 0.but same id not create again i need only changed todayworker status?.

output:
  "_id" : ObjectId("542012b5b79597180574255d"),
      "userId" : ObjectId("54052de21b7a0d0b00739cf9"),
      "createdDate" : ISODate("2014-09-22T12:14:`45.78Z`"),
      "todayWorker" : 2,

i was use given the following code but not working properly please give me a solution anybody

```
workerschema code
var workerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
userId:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
todayWorker:{type:Number,default:0,enum:[0,1,2]}, 
createdDate:{type: Date,default:Date.now }
```

});

```
  //delete worker code(while delete properly changed todatworker status) 
var options1={multi:true};
        //Worker.remove(selection,function(err,status){
            Worker.update(selection,{$set:{todayWorker:2}},options1,function(err,status){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            else
            {
                res.json({"success":true,"message":"Workers Deleted"});
            }
        });
//add worker code (but insert time not changed todayworker status)
var idObjects=createObjectIds(idsarray);        
    var selection={_id:{$in:idObjects}};
    //console.log(selection);
    if(todayWorker==0){
        var projection={_id:1};
        var callback1=function(err,users){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            else{
                var count1=users.length;                
                for(var i=0;i<count1;i++){
                    Worker.findOneOrCreate({userId:users[i].id},{userId:users[i].id,todayWorker:todayWorker},function(err,worker){
                        //Worker.findAndModify({query:{userId:users[i].id},update{$setOnInsert:{todayWorker:"todayWorker"}}},{ upsert: true },function(err,Worker){
                            //Worker.update({userId:users[i].id},{$setOnInsert:{ userId:users[i].id,todayWorker:todayWorker,createdDate:Date.now()}},{ upsert: true },function(err,Worker){
                        if(err)
                            res.send(err);
                        else
                        {

                            count2++;
                            if(count2==count1)

                                res.json({"status":true,"message":"Worker Added"});
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        User.find(selection,projection,callback1);
}
else
{
    res.send("No user found");
}
```

};

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: update and insert function run on same query without duplicate

Comment: when i remove id todayworker changed  to 2.suppose insert same id todayworker changed to 0.i was use lot of query but didn't work properly.please give me solution.thank you

Comment: I getting tried to use multiple query please give me a best solution..thanking you.